# When Gibbs Sampling is fast/slow to converge?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, bayesian-network

Are there any heuristic/theories showing that on what kind of Bayesian models the convergence of Gibbs sampling is fast/slow?

For example, from my limited experience, I feel (may be wrong) when a model has many "triangle relations" (A->B, A->C, B->C), the convergence is likely to be slow.

The practical value for this question is that we might chose to modify the model structure when we meet such models considering the convergence speed. Any reference or personal experience are warmly welcomed!

Comment: what's a triangle relation?

Comment: By "triangle" relation, I mean, for example, for r.v. {A,B,C}, B depends on A, C depends on A, and C depends on B. On a Bayesian network, the three forms a triangle.

Comment: Why do you think that would be slower to converge?  Also, in a Bayesian network, if B depends on A, then A depends on B.

Comment: This is just based on limit experience... And I guessing this way because it forms a loop and if there is no loop, fast algorithm (like belief-propagation) would be available, though there is no logic that Gibbs sampler will also perform better in this case. And sorry for my terminology, by "A depends on B" I am meaning the relation between A and B in the model is described/defined by P(A|B)

Comment: When the joint distribution has a strong curvature, as in, e.g., a boomerang sgape, moving on this distribution using the conditionals is very slow.

Comment: Changing the model structure is not an option since Gibbs is used to simulate from a given model. Changing the parameterisation of the model is possible, though.

Comment: Thx! Would you please provide some reference on reparamerisation?